# JAXRS UriInfo with DefaultValue

Tags: java, jax-rs

I'm using `UriInfo` inside an object, i have a validation on params inside request, i did the following, however i still get nulls, `searchCount`value is null however i set `DefaultValue` as shown below:

```
private final UriInfo uriInfo;
private final String LONGITUDE = "lon";
private final String LATITUDE = "lat";
private final @DefaultValue("10000") String RANGE = "range";
private final @DefaultValue("") String EVENT_TYPE = "eType";
private final @DefaultValue("") String PLACE_TYPE = "pType";
private final String SEARCH_COUNT = "count";

public NearByRequestWrapper(UriInfo uriInfo) {
this.uriInfo = uriInfo;
}

@DefaultValue("50") @Size(min = 10, max = 100)
public String searchCount() {
return uriInfo.getQueryParameters().getFirst(SEARCH_COUNT);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are misusing the [`@DefaultValue`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/DefaultValue.html) annotation. See the following quote from the [javadoc](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/DefaultValue.html):

> Defines the default value of request metadata that is bound using one of the following annotations: `PathParam`, `QueryParam`, `MatrixParam`, `CookieParam`, `FormParam`, or `HeaderParam`. The default value is used if the corresponding metadata is not present in the request.

---

If know the parameters you expect to receive, you don't need to use [`UriInfo`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/core/UriInfo.html).

You can use the [`@QueryParam`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/QueryParam.html) annotations on method arguments to map the query parameters and then use the [`@DefaultValue`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/DefaultValue.html) annotation to define the default value for such parameter:

```java
@Path("foo")
public class MyResource {

    @GET
    public String searchCount(@QueryParam("lon") String longitude,
                              @QueryParam("lat") String latitute,
                              @QueryParam("range") @DefaultValue("10000") String range,
                              @QueryParam("eType") String eventType,
                              @QueryParam("pType") String placeType,
                              @QueryParam("count") @DefaultValue("50") String count) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Alternatively you could use [`@QueryParam`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/QueryParam.html) on resource method fields:

```java
@Path("foo")
public class MyResource {

    @QueryParam("lon")
    private String longitude;

    @QueryParam("lat")
    private String latitute;

    @QueryParam("range")
    @DefaultValue("10000")
    private String range;

    @QueryParam("eType")
    private String eventType;

    @QueryParam("pType")
    private String placeType;

    @QueryParam("count")
    @DefaultValue("50")
    private String count;

    @GET
    public String searchCount() {
        ...
    }
 }
```

If you want to reuse the query parameters across multiple resource classes, you could aggregate them in a bean and use such bean as a method parameter annotated with [`@BeanParam`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/BeanParam.html):

```java
public class SearchParams {

    @QueryParam("lon")
    private String longitude;

    @QueryParam("lat")
    private String latitute;

    @QueryParam("range")
    @DefaultValue("10000")
    private String range;

    @QueryParam("eType")
    private String eventType;

    @QueryParam("pType")
    private String placeType;

    @QueryParam("count")
    @DefaultValue("50")
    private String count;

    // Getters and setters
}
```

```java
@Path("foo")
public class MyResource {

    @GET
    public String searchCount(@BeanParam SearchParams searchParams) {
        ...
    }
 }
```

---

The [`@Size`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/validation/constraints/Size.html) annotation can be used with the above mentioned approaches.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work like that, how would Java know that method has anything to do with the query string? Here's an example:

```
public void foo(@DefaultValue("50") @QueryParam("count") int count){}
```